# disable-output-escaping="yes" is not working

Tags: xslt

I have the following code

```
<db:P_RECEIVED_XML>
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="oraext:get-content-as-string(/ns0:ReceivedMessage/MessageContent/*)"/>
      </db:P_RECEIVED_XML>
```

when i test this transformation, by giving the value as

```
<MessageContent xmlns="">
      <any_0 xmlns="##any">
         <note>
         <name>GENERAL</name>
         <value><![CDATA[test ~<!@#$%^&*()_~!@#$%^&*()_+]]></value>
      </note>
      </any_0>
   </MessageContent>
```

the output rendered is

```
<db:P_RECEIVED_XML><any_0 xmlns="##any">
         <note>
         <name>GENERAL</name>
         <value>test ~&lt;!@#$%^&amp;*()_~!@#$%^&amp;*()_+</value>
      </note>
      </any_0>
</db:P_RECEIVED_XML>
```

Here `&` is converted to `&amp;` though i have used disable-output-escaping="yes".

Kindly help.

Comment: Please post code that can show the problem by running it **as is**!

Comment: It depends what is doing the rendering, `disable-output-escaping` only works when the XSLT procrssor is the one responsible for serializing the output xml to bytes, if it's in the middle of a pipeline producing its output as some sort of dom tree that is then subject to further processing by other components before serialization then d-o-e will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged your question as XSLT. In XSLT, using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="your-node-here" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

would have disabled the escaping, and **not** output `&` as `&amp;`.

If you are seeing a different result, it's probably a result of your using an extension `oraext:get-content-as-string()` function. Try removing it and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

disable-output-escaping only works if the result tree produced by the XSLT processor is immediately serialized, and if the serialization is under the control of the the XSLT processor. That means, for example, that it doesn't work if the result is written to a DOM tree, and you then use the DOM serialization to produce lexical XML.

XSLT processors are allowed to ignore disable-output-escaping entirely.

So it basically depends on what XSLT processor you are using and how you are running it.